# Inner Join não funciona - Erro 1054

Tags: mysql

Alguém poderia me explicar por que essa query não funciona?

```
select mensagem.mnsg, aluno.nome as nomea, aluno.curso as cursoa 
from mensagem 
inner join aluno on aluno.rm=mensagem.RM 
order by id asc;


-- Table aluno

CREATE TABLE `aluno` (
`RM` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Turma_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Foto` TINYBLOB NULL,
`Nome` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Email` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Senha` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`RM`),
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

-- Table mensagem

CREATE TABLE `mensagem` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`RM` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`mnsg` TEXT NULL,
`RM_PROF` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Turma_ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
;

-- Table turma

CREATE TABLE `turma` (
`Turma_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`curso` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ano` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`QNT_ALUNO` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Turma_ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: Retorna algum erro?

Comment: Mas o select está ali amigo :(

Comment: O erro retornado está no título, 1054

Comment: Tenta isso:  select mensagem.mnsg, mensagem.RM, aluno.nome as nomea, aluno.curso as cursoa, aluno.rm from mensagem inner join aluno on aluno.rm=mensagem.RM order by id asc;

Comment: Ops, como não estava na mesma formatação, acabei não vendo, foi mal, vou excluir meu comentário.

Comment: Estou recebendo muitos votos negativos, o que eu fiz de errado?

Comment: Quando são coisas muito básicas ou pedidos para fazer o código, geralmente as pessoas não gostam e negativam. No seu caso acredito que foi falta de atenção para resolver o problema, fique mais atento à estrutura do BD

Comment: Entendi, obrigado

Comment: Não sei se é o caso, mas tem opção de chat no Stack, acredito que sirva para esses propósito também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select mensagem.mnsg, 
      aluno.nome as nomea, 
      turma.curso as cursoa
From mensagem 
Inner join aluno on 
     aluno.rm=mensagem.RM
Inner join turma on
     turma.Turma_ID = mensagem.Turma_ID
Order by id asc;
```

Você estava selecionando o curso no aluno, sendo que o curso está na tabela turma.

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo!

Answer (score 1):

Você está buscando aluno.curso em aluno, mas na criação da tabela aluno não existe a coluna curso...

Junte a tabela curso através do turma_ID que vai dar certo.

assim que chegar em casa edito a resposta com o código para você.

Comment: Muito obrigado Luis! Você me ajudou novamente!